# jQuery UI icons show up in debug deploy but not release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an ASP MVC app that uses jQuery UI for the datepicker and accordion widgets. When running locally and when deployed to the dev/debug web app on azure the icons for them (buttons to change months, arrow for accordions) show up just fine.

However once deployed to the release/production web app, they do not. The widgets still work just fine, but for some reason it refuses to include the jquery ui images associated with the widgets. It does try to load the resource, but it comes back 404.

I am deploying to Azure, and the web app configurations are the same for the debug/release web apps on the azure end.

I'm not really sure which config files from my project are relevant to the problem, so i'll wait to post those until someone tells me to.

I use the minified jquery ui css in my bundle config, and I know it bundles correctly since it actually tries to load the icons in production, but returns 404 on the icons themselves.

- Content

  - images

    - ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
  - jquery-ui.min.css

and in the jquery-ui.min.css it looks for them from the relative path like

`background-image:url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png")`

So when it gets deployed to the release build it must re arrange where the content directory is relative to the css file or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your files are marked as content and in a path relative to the ASP App Root, make sure your bundles are genn'ing the same every configuration. Like so:

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssthemebundle").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

This works in our solution regradless of config. We did have a problem at one point with Release resource paths getting horked, but this bundle pathing works well now.

Note: The resource images referenced in the theme css files are relative to the theme folder, not "~/". So the jquery-ui css urls should remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've had some more pressing things to work on lately but as soon as I get around to fixing this bug I will revisit your answer and provide any necessary feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Just to confirm that the issue is with the image path - try replacing the image path with complete URL like

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon
{
  background-image: url("http://your_site/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```

That would work!

However, this change can not be done, as it is suggested to make changes to the library files. So, moving the images to the same folder seems to be working.

Refer the below link. Though its related to telerik controls, the problem is similar.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/asp-mvc-css-minification-breaks-kendo-bootstrap#5_PIevmzV0iIW0G9Kx8R-g

Hope it helps someone.

Good luck!